# cakephp Encrypted Files

Tags: php, cakephp, obfuscation, ioncube

I have got new client and site I am working on is developed in cakephp with previous developer.

I have found that all core files of cakephp are somehow encrypted. Sample code of one file **app_controller.php** is listed below.

```
    <?php //003ab
if(!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader')){$__oc=strtolower(substr(php_uname(),0,3));$__ln='ioncube_loader_'.$__oc.'_'.substr(phpversion(),0,3).(($__oc=='win')?'.dll':'.so');@dl($__ln);if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}$__ln='/ioncube/'.$__ln;$__oid=$__id=realpath(ini_get('extension_dir'));$__here=dirname(__FILE__);if(strlen($__id)>1&&$__id[1]==':'){$__id=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__id,2));$__here=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__here,2));}$__rd=str_repeat('/..',substr_count($__id,'/')).$__here.'/';$__i=strlen($__rd);while($__i--){if($__rd[$__i]=='/'){$__lp=substr($__rd,0,$__i).$__ln;if(file_exists($__oid.$__lp)){$__ln=$__lp;break;}}}@dl($__ln);}else{die('The file '.__FILE__." is corrupted.\n");}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}echo('Site error: the file <b>'.__FILE__.'</b> requires the ionCube PHP Loader '.basename($__ln).' to be installed by the site administrator.');exit(199);
?>
4+oV56OZtfUNjYBOUjjBj3zgIUeijyktONXYzvIiRk1OYyGjpaPx6pxmkVge1tFO/vd4YcXcUY89
3rUZYxaPxPV01zdEqdnQpXC4lxDB4KtNI1BcyCpbhy0TE2wttSJYM/jkYw1I5AQxUYnMMNd5YsG4
UYdC8KKBKvUZi+6Sjs7vmLq7RU87BaHBXFQYbecak0PeKMA0XOH63aQ09P1A5i8INsjTtgr7rKRH
.
.
.
.
W+P29smSO46z3bBNF/0q4zwJszMmt7xB+MUM57Hia7fpXhB0tmlk
```

Can Anybody help me to decrytp that file or give me any guidance how this would be implemented

Thanks in advance for great help.

Comment: You sure that this is not just code obfuscation? Also, did you read the information on cakephp on the tag site? http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cakephp/info

Comment: within the script you find `Site error: the file <b>'.__FILE__.'</b> requires the ionCube PHP Loader` .. and a search for ionCube finds this page: http://www.ioncube.com/

Comment: @harpax the "ionCube Loader" string in the clear part of the code is a dead givaway as well :) The visible "encryption" is of course base 64 encoding.